# How can I run an ASP.NET application on Apache Web Server?

Tags: asp.net, apache

I need to run an asp.net application on apache, can anyone suggest how this can be done?

Comment: http://dotnet.tekyt.info/?p=12

Answer (score 2):

Try this one [ASp.net on Apache](http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2005/09/11/424852.aspx). Check around [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET).